# Why and When do I use the New keyword when declaring a new recordset in Access VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado, adodb, recordset

What is the difference between

```
Dim rs as New adodb.recordset
```

and

```
Dim rs as adodb.recordset
```

In what situations would I want to use the New statement or not use it? For context, I am working on a ADODB access application that connects to a SQL Server Back end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the keyword 'New' do in VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652671/what-does-the-keyword-new-do-in-vba)

Comment: @Mat'sMug

This question is specific to Microsoft Access and Recordsets which differs from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652671/what-does-the-keyword-new-do-in-vba

Comment: I added a note specific to `ADODB.Recordset`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `New` keyword creates a *new* instance of an object, here of type `ADODB.Recordset`.

An object variable needs to have a *reference* before it can be accessed, so this:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM TableName"
```

...will blow up at run-time with error #91 - "Object or With block variable not set". The important part of that message here is "not set".

When you do:

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
```

You're really doing:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
```

The `Set` keyword is used to *assign a reference* to an object variable.

---

Specifically about `ADODB.Recordset`, I'd say you don't *usually* want to `New` up a recordset. Instead, you'll *get* one by running a parameterized `ADODB.Command` (e.g. when a command runs a `SELECT` statement, you'll receive a `Recordset` result).

---

I'd advise against using the `As New` shortcut in procedure scope. Mostly because of this:

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim c As New Collection
    c.Add "Test"
    Set c = Nothing
    Debug.Print c.Count 'what happens here?
End Sub
```

If you think the above code blows up because `c` is not "set" anymore when `c.Count` is accessed, you got bitten.

This code behaves as expected:

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection
    c.Add "Test"
    Set c = Nothing
    Debug.Print c.Count 'what happens here? that's right, boom!
End Sub
```