# Making a Collection of Sheet Names

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to generate a collection of all the sheets in a workbook.

```vb
Sub collMaker()

Dim coll As Collection, ws As Worksheet, x As String

For i = 2 To Application.Sheets.count
    x = Application.Sheets(i).name
    coll.Add Item:=x, Key:=x
Next i

End Sub
```

I get a runtime error '91' on the `coll.add` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `New` when creating your collection, or it will just be defined as `Nothing`, and you cannot add something to nothing.

It's also a good idea to `Dim` all of your variables.

```
Sub collMaker()

Dim coll As New Collection, ws As Worksheet, x As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To Application.Sheets.Count
     x = Application.Sheets(i).Name
     coll.Add Item:=x, Key:=x
Next i

End Sub
```

[What does the keyword 'New' do in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652671/what-does-the-keyword-new-do-in-vba)

Comment: @Alastair: We here, when somebody answer our question (in a very helpful way), tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. If somebody else will search for a similar issue, he will know that the answer solved your problem and the code works (now).

Comment: @FaneDuru, sorry, I tried to do that when the question was answered, but it was too early for me to click.