# Excel VBA Macro: User Defined Type Not Defined

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm getting the above error when trying to execute this macros. I'm pretty new to Macros and coding in general so please forgive the ignorance.

```
Sub DeleteEmptyRows()

Dim oTable As Table, oRow As Row, _
TextInRow As Boolean, i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
    For Each oRow In oTable.Rows

        TextInRow = False

        For i = 2 To oRow.Cells.Count
            If Len(oRow.Cells(i).Range.Text) > 2 Then
                'end of cell marker is actually 2 characters
                TextInRow = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If TextInRow = False Then
            oRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This appears to be code for Word, but you've tagged it as Excel. Where are you trying to run it?

Comment: `Row` and `Table` are not a variable type

Comment: Yes my apologies, the code is for a mail merge in Word, executed in Excel

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your error is caused by these:

```
Dim oTable As Table, oRow As Row,
```

These types, `Table` and `Row` are not variable types native to Excel.  You can resolve this in one of two ways:

1. Include a reference to the Microsoft Word object model.  Do this from Tools | References, then add reference to MS Word.  While not strictly necessary, you *may* like to fully qualify the objects like `Dim oTable as Word.Table, oRow as Word.Row`.  This is called early-binding.  [image]
2. Alternatively, to use late-binding method, you must declare the objects as generic `Object` type: `Dim oTable as Object, oRow as Object`.  With this method, you do not need to add the reference to Word, but you also lose the intellisense assistance in the VBE.

I have not tested your code but I suspect `ActiveDocument` won't work in Excel with method #2, unless you properly scope it to an instance of a Word.Application object.  I don't see that anywhere in the code you have provided.  An example  would be like:

```
Sub DeleteEmptyRows()
Dim wdApp as Object
Dim oTable As Object, As Object, _
TextInRow As Boolean, i As Long

Set wdApp = GetObject(,"Word.Application")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each oTable In wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables
```

Answer (score 0):

I am late for the party. Try replacing as below, mine worked perfectly-
"DOMDocument" to "MSXML2.DOMDocument60"
"XMLHTTP" to "MSXML2.XMLHTTP60"

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub DeleteEmptyRows()  

    Worksheets("YourSheetName").Activate
    On Error Resume Next
    Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

The following code will delete all rows on a sheet(YourSheetName) where the content of Column A is blank.

EDIT: User Defined Type Not Defined is caused by "oTable As Table" and "oRow As Row". Replace Table and Row with Object to resolve the error and make it compile.

Comment: It may compile, but will probably not run, without the relevant Word objects, either via early binding or late binding, as in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24263432/111794) answer.