# "User-defined type not defined" Error

Tags: vb6

Hi im trying to create a simple program involving an object and a class within
VB 6.0.

The error message i get is: "User-defined type not defined"

The highlighted code that VB suspects is "Dim Bob As Ball"

My defined class is as follows:

```
Dim Bob As Object

Public Sub Ball()

Dim Circlex As Integer
Dim Circley As Integer

Public Sub makeBall()
 Circlex = 3000
 Circley = 3000
End Sub

Private Sub moveBall()
 Circle (Circlex, Circley), 200
End Sub

End Sub
```

My code for the only form in my project is:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
 Command1.Visible = False
 Command1.Enabled = False
 vbalProgressBar1.Visible = True
 Timer1.Enabled = True
 Beep
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
 Form1.Width = 6000
 Form1.Height = 6000
 Dim Bob As Ball
 Dim Bob As New Ball
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
 If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to be a quitter?!"
 , vbYesNo,"Quit?") = vbYes Then  
 Unload Me
 Set Form1 = Nothing
Else
 Cancel = 1
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
 Bob = moveBall(Circlex, Circley)
End Sub
```

Im not sure why the suspected line of code is incorrect, but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: unless you have a class or structure named `Ball` the error msg is correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User Defined Type Not Defined - Excel Macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261557/user-defined-type-not-defined-excel-macros)

Answer (score 0):

VB6 doesn't use code style that you coded.
You have to follow these method to make code work with your intention.
1. make classmodule
2. set its name 'Ball'
3. paste this code on classmodule

```
Dim Circlex As Integer
Dim Circley As Integer

Public Sub makeBall()
 Circlex = 3000
 Circley = 3000
End Sub

Private Sub moveBall()
 Circle (Circlex, Circley), 200
End Sub
```

4. paste code on your form

   ```
   Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Command1.Visible = False
   Command1.Enabled = False
   vbalProgressBar1.Visible = True
   Timer1.Enabled = True
   Beep

   End Sub

   Private Sub Form_Load()
    Form1.Width = 6000
    Form1.Height = 6000
    Dim Bob As New Ball
   End Sub

   Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to be a quitter?!"
    , vbYesNo,"Quit?") = vbYes Then  
    Unload Me
    Set Form1 = Nothing
   Else
    Cancel = 1
   End If
   End Sub

   Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Bob.moveBall(Circlex, Circley)
   End Sub
   ```

Additionally, VB6 doesn't support style like

```
Sub A()
    Sub B()
    End Sub
End Sub
```