# ALM Defects list failing with 'User defined type not defined'

Tags: excel, alm, vba

I wanted to extract list of defects using a filter criteria. I tried the VBA code from OTA [here](http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/de/12.53/api_refs/ota/topic141.html), but compile fails on the following declarations with **User defined type not defined**:

```
Dim BugFact As BugFactory
Dim BugFilter As TDFilter
Dim bugList As List
Dim theBug As Bug
```

Note: I do not have administrative privileges on ALM.

The full VBA code:

```
Sub BugFilter()

    Dim BugFact As BugFactory
    Dim BugFilter As TDFilter
    Dim bugList As List
    Dim theBug As Bug
    Dim i%, msg$

' Get the bug factory filter.
    'tdc is the global TDConnection object.
    Set BugFact = tdc.BugFactory
    Set BugFilter = BugFact.Filter

' Set the filter values.
    BugFilter.Filter("BG_STATUS") = "Closed"
    BugFilter.order("BG_PRIORITY") = 1
    MsgBox BugFilter.Text

'Create a list of defects from the filter
' and show a few of them.
    Set bugList = BugFilter.NewList
    msg = "Number of defects = " & bugList.Count & Chr(13)
    For Each theBug In bugList
       msg = msg & theBug.ID & ", " & theBug.Summary & ", " _
          & theBug.Status & ", " & theBug.Priority & Chr(13)
       i = i + 1
       If i > 10 Then Exit For
    Next
    MsgBox msg

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User Defined Type Not Defined - Excel Macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261557/user-defined-type-not-defined-excel-macros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the **OTA COM Type library** (see [here](https://sumeetkushwah.com/2015/03/19/connecting-almqc-using-hps-otaopen-test-architecture-api/)); otherwise your program will not know about the OTA types such as `BugFactory` and `TDFilter`.

Comment: Thanks Zev Spitz for your Inputs. The above mentioned issue is now resolved. But now getting another error as Object required on "Set BugFact = tdc.BugFactory"

Comment: If the answer has solved the problem in your question, accept it (by clicking on the green checkbox next to the answer). If the answer has helped you, then upvote it (by clicking on the up arrow next to the answer).

Comment: You probably need to initialize the `tdc` object:  `Dim tdc As TDConnection:
 Set tdc = New TDConnection`