# Unable to work with word applications from excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, user-defined-types

I am trying to open word document from the excel but stuck at the first line  when I am using the below code. I have added reference still get the compile error user- defined type not defined.

```
Dim oApp As Word.Application
Dim oSec As Word.Section
Dim oDoc As Word.Document

Set AppWord = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
Set oApp = New Word.Application
Set oDoc = oApp.Documents.Add
```

Comment: Did you tick the Word library in References?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['User Defined Type Not Defined' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261557/user-defined-type-not-defined-error)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference in the VBA context by opening VBA (Developer Tab, Click: Visual Basic), Select your Workbook and Click from the menu: Tools, References.

In the references list find the Word Object Library and make sure it is checked before clicking OK

[image]

Now try again, and don't forget to make oApp visible! :

```
Sub Test()
   Dim oApp As Word.Application
   Dim oSec As Word.Section
   Dim oDoc As Word.Document

   Set AppWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   Set oApp = New Word.Application
   Set oDoc = oApp.Documents.Add

   oApp.Visible = True

End Sub
```