# how to update table in word?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am working on the bearing report. I have to copy and find the relevant bearing data from the excel file and paste it in the word table. I have figured out the codes to

1. To go to the relavant location in the word file and paste some data in desired word document.

   ```
   Sub CreateNewWordDoc()
       Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
       Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
       Dim i As Integer
       Dim arr(12)
       'Bearing numbers I need to search
       arr(0) = "(249_L), 38,7 %"
       arr(1) = "(248_R), 38,7 %"
       arr(2) = "(249_M), 38,7 "
       arr(3) = "(3560), 38,7 "
       arr(4) = "(3550), 38,7 %"
       arr(5) = "(349_), 38,7 %"
       arr(6) = "(348_), 38,7 %"
       arr(7) = "(451), 38,7 %"
       arr(8) = "(450L), 38,7 "
       arr(9) = "(450R), 38,7 "
       arr(10) = "(151), 38,7 %"
       arr(11) = "(150L), 38,7 %"
       arr(12) = "(150R), 38,7 %"
       Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
       wrdApp.Visible = True 
       'location of my word document

       Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("E:\ShareDrive_Ruehl\full-flexible-MBS-models_report\example-report\FullFlexibleGearbox - Copy (2).docx")
       wrdDoc.Activate

       wrdApp.Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
       'for loop to reach all bearing location
       For i = 0 To 12
           With wrdApp.Selection
               With .Find
                   .ClearFormatting
                   .MatchWildcards = False
                   .MatchWholeWord = False
                   .Text = arr(i)
                   .Execute
               End With
               ' Here is where I need to paste my copied data.

               .InsertAfter "I can just paste this shit"
               .HomeKey unit:=wdStory
           End With
       Next   
   End Sub
   ```
2. Go to the location in the excel file, find the relevant data and copy the data related to that and here is the code for that.

   ```
   Sub CopyToWord()
       'Copy the range Which you want to paste in a New Word Document
       Cells.Find(What:=arr(0), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
         , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
         MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
       ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1:g8").Select
       Selection.Copy
   End Sub
   ```

I have written both these codes to be operated from Excel VBA. But Now I have to combine both and paste the copied data from 2nd code to the table which is located in the 1st code (The location of the place is not just after the location where i find the word. To go to that location I know the code and can be better understood by the pics given below.).

This is the code for me to select the data in the **word** where I need to replace. I need to write similar in word and replace that with the copied data

```
Sub pasting()
    Dim sSample, rResult As String
    sSample = "(450R), 38,7 % "

    Set rRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=sSample, _
      Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop
    Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.EndKey unit:=wdLine
    Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.EndKey unit:=wdLine
    Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=1

    Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=5, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.MoveLeft unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=5, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, Though I have copied the data what I want I am not able to arrive at the solution. I don't know how to paste data in the existing table.

This picture explains better. I need to search data of bearing 248_R in excel and paste that in word.
This is the Word file

[image]

this is the Excel file

[image]

Comment: Why don't you (instead of this extensive VBA script) just link/embed your Excel data like explained in [Embed an Excel worksheet in a Word document](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/embed.html) or [Linking Excel Data Into Word Documents](http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/158-linking-excel-data-into-word-documents)? That would be a lot easier than using a script and would update the data in Word automatically. Don't re-invent the wheel!

Comment: Peh's suggestion looks rather attractive. However, if that doesn't work for you note that you can't paste data from an Excel table into an existing Word table. You would have to write the contents of each Excel cell into each existing Word cell.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Peh But I am writing a code with which, if I pull in other bearing data set it must update automatically. I mean if i put other excel sheet with same bearing names but different values, it must update automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CreateNewWordDoc()
    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document



    Dim arr(12)
    'Bearing numbers I need to search
    arr(0) = "(249_L), 38,7 %"
    arr(1) = "(248_R), 38,7 %"
    arr(2) = "(249_M), 38,7 "
    arr(3) = "(3560), 38,7 "
    arr(4) = "(3550), 38,7 %"
    arr(5) = "(349_), 38,7 %"
    arr(6) = "(348_), 38,7 %"
    arr(7) = "(451), 38,7 %"
    arr(8) = "(450L), 38,7 %"
    arr(9) = "(450R), 38,7 %"
    arr(10) = "(151), 38,7 %"
    arr(11) = "(150L), 38,7 %"
    arr(12) = "(150R), 38,7 %"

    range2 = 6


    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True
    'location of my word document

    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("E:\Siemens\FullFlexibleGearbox.docx")
    wrdDoc.Activate

    wrdApp.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    'for loop to reach all bearing location
    For i = 0 To 12
             Cells.Find(What:=arr(i), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
             LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
                ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1:G8").Select
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Selection.Copy

        With wrdApp.Selection
            With .Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .Text = arr(i)
                .Execute
            End With
            .MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
            .MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
            .MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=6, Extend:=wdExtend
            .MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=6, Extend:=wdExtend
            .Paste
            .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory



        End With
    Next
    End Sub
```

Thanks for your support people. :)

Answer (score 2):

Forget copying and pasting. Instead once you have found your data (in 2) assign the range to a variable of type variant. it will now be an array inside your variable
Now you can loop through this assigning each element to a cell within your table 
I'm at work so I can't see your images, but remember that cells in a Word table are referred to as Cell(row,column) - so you can write

```
 with Wrdapp.documents(1).tables(1)
      For x = 0 to ubound(v,1)
          for y = 0 to ubound(v,2)
            .cell(x + 1,y + 1).range.text = v(x,y)
          next y
      next x

 end with
```

to copy an array V into the the first table in a document
(The +1 in cell is because arrays count from zero, but Word tables run from one
so v(0,0) needs to go to cell(1,1)

Hopefully that should get you started