# Access 2010 Issue: Moved from Office 2013 to Office 2010, "User-defined type not defined" error

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, ms-access-2010

First off let me say I know basically nothing about Access Databases. I recently inherited this one by my position after the previous gentlemen left. Before they left they downgraded Office from 2013 to 2010 (unsure why, vague hints to license issues).

Now after the upgrade the database gives the following error:

[image: First Error Pop-up]

Followed by highlighting this line (pictures lightly edited):

[image: Lines Highlighted]

Here's the section it highlights:

```
Public Sub g_MailMerge(strTemplate As String)
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strQuery As String

    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application

    On Error GoTo g_MailMergeError

    DoCmd.Hourglass True
   'Delete the rtf file
```

I've attempted numerous fixes regarding the References, but all solutions I've found from Google has come up with nothing so far, though I'm honestly not completely sure what I'm looking for.

Workstation Info:

- Mac 27" running Windows Parallels with Windows 7 Pro; all latest versions
- Office 2010

If you need access to the full code of Module1 or otherwise let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['User Defined Type Not Defined' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261557/user-defined-type-not-defined-error) -- All you are missing is the reference to the MS Word object model (of the current Office version).

Answer (score 2):

From the VBA environment, go to Tools -> References menu
Check if there is any missing library. Perhaps, uncheck the old word library and check the new version