# Excel VBA - Difference Between CreateObject and New Internet Explorer

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone please explain to me if there is a difference between

```
Set objIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
```

and

```
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
```

Comment: please read: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between using the New keyword and calling CreateObject in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170070/what-are-the-differences-between-using-the-new-keyword-and-calling-createobject)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is late binding, and the second one is early binding. Early binding also requires a reference in the project whereas late binding does not.