# When does C# Perform Late Bound Call?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# early and late binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484214/c-sharp-early-and-late-binding)

I want to ask that When does C# Perform Late Bound Call?
In which circumstances does late bound occurs?

Comment: This might be helful [C# early and late binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484214/c-sharp-early-and-late-binding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are boud to there address so that they could be 
executed. if the address of the functions are known during 
compile time the compiler binds it, this kind of binding is 
known as compile time binding or early binding. Where as 
when we dont know which function needs to be exucuted 
during compile time (as in case of dynamic polymorphism), 
compiler uses mechaninsm of virtual table and binds the 
function address during runtime. this is known as runtime 
binding or late binding.

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism is a good example of late bound call.