# VBA auto-complete / suggestion

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Typing 'Activesheet.' will not bring up a list of suggestions whereas other classes will. How do I bring up this autosuggestion screen in the coding screen as I am typing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make VBE helper show up when using functions/commands to other office applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434262/make-vbe-helper-show-up-when-using-functions-commands-to-other-office-applicatio)

Comment: [This answer may prove to be userful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25437898/3198973).

Comment: Property ActiveSheet As Object ... therefore no intelisence.

Comment: @dee How do I make the ActiveSheet bring up the intelligent suggestions?

Comment: Dim someSheet As Worksheet Set someSheet = ActiveSheet, then use someSheet, there you have intelisece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Excel, typing `ActiveSheet` is invoking a property of the default object, Excel.Application . If you are working in Access (based on your tags), the default object is Access.Application, which doesn't have an ActiveSheet property. Instead, Access, will see `ActiveSheet` as an undimensioned variant variable. To get the Intellisense that you seek, you must:

- Have a reference to the Excel library
- Declare a variable of type Excel.Application
- Type a dot after that variable's name and you'll see the ActiveSheet in the Intellisense

or (from @dee)

```
Dim someSheet As Worksheet  'As Excel.Worksheet in Access
Set someSheet = ActiveSheet 'As Excel.ActiveSheet in Access
'use someSheet, there you have intellisense
```

If you type `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, you'll get a helpful compile error when you refer to something that doesn't actually exist or is mis-spelled, instead of accidentally declaring a new variable.

Comment: please include Dee's comment suggestion with this answer and I will mark it as the answer. "Dim someSheet As Worksheet Set someSheet = ActiveSheet, then use someSheet, there you have intelisece."