# Having a same variable in both sub and super classes

Tags: java

In this question the output gives as Rose0. But when I go through the logic I feel the answer must be Rose100 instead of Rose0.  How does compiler differentiate the i s in both classes. Since Rosea extends _39 class it has the super class i as well. But in line 1 if I change super.i then Im getting Rose100. How this differs?

```
class _39 {
  int i;

  _39(){
    i=100;
    foo();
  }

  public void foo(){
    System.out.println("Flower"+i);}
  }
}

public class Rosea extends _39{

  int i=200;

  Rosea(){ 
      i=300;
  }

  public void foo(){
    System.out.println("Rose"+i);
  } //line 1

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Rosea();
  }
}
```

Comment: In the scope of the subclass, the subclass variable hides the superclass one. That's all that's happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the variable `i` in the subclass will *hide* the variable in the super class. So you'll have to write `super.i` in `Rosea` if you want to access `_39.i`.

Second: Even if you call `foo` in the super class, the call will be made to the implementation in the subclass.

```
...

    _39() {
        i = 100;
        foo();     <--------------- this calls this
    }                                            |
                                                 |
...                                              |
                                                 |
public class Rosea extends _39 {                 |
    ...                                          |
    public void foo() {                  <-------'
        System.out.println("Rose" + i);
    }
    ...
}
```

And in the `Rosea.foo` `i` refers to `Rosea`s version of `i` since `_39.i` is hidden.

All methods in Java are virtual, i.e. it's the runtime type of the object that determines which method is invoked. (*Even* if the call is made from within the super class.)

Further reading:

- [What is the difference between Early and Late Binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580/what-is-early-and-late-binding)

Answer (score 1):

The variables with same name in the derived class **hide** the ones in base class. So in function `Rosea::foo()`, the `i` of derived class will be used. As you wrote in your question, if you want to use `i` of base class, you must explicitly write `super.i`.