# Understanding VBA Object Variables

Tags: vba, excel

I'm learning Visual Basic for Applications, and I'm a little unsure of when to use procedures. For example, is a procedure needed every time an object variable is created? Or can an object variable be created without being executed as a procedure?

Could I have just

```
Dim wkbInventory As Workbook
Set wkbInventory = Application.Workbooks("name.xlsm")
```

Thank you!

Comment: If there is a workbook open called **name.xlsm** then it is in the current application instance's [Workbooks Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224505%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and you can declare a variable and `Set` in that manner. If it is **not** open then you need to open it first (or simultaneously like `Set wkbInventory = Workbooks.Open("name.xlsm")` ).

Comment: Thank you very much, to everyone. All these threads are helping my understanding of VBA Object Variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A object variable can be declared outside a procedure. So the

`Dim wkbInventory As Workbook`

can be in the `Declarations` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd897495%28v=office.12%29.aspx#odc_ac2007_bk_BeginningAccess2007VBA_Chapt2_CreatingModules) .

The `scope` of the variable is dependent on where the declaration happens. See http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Scope.aspx.

But a variable can't be instantiated outside a procedure or function. So the

`Set wkbInventory = Application.Workbooks("name.xlsm")`

must be inside the `Procedures` within a sub procedure or a function.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all of the work in VBA happens inside of macros. You can declare variables outside of macros (although this changes the variable's scope compared to declaring it inside a macro) and specify some compiler options but that's about it.

This is OK:

```
Option Explicit

' Declaration
Dim c As Collection

Sub foo()

Set c = New Collection
c.Add "hello", "world"
MsgBox c.Count

End Sub
```

whereas this will generate a compile error - "Invalid outside procedure":

```
Option Explicit

' Declaration
Dim c As Collection
' This causes an error
Set c = New Collection

Sub foo()

c.Add "hello", "world"
MsgBox c.Count

End Sub
```

If you use implicit creation with your variable declaration (Dim x As New y) then that works outside of a macro. Not all objects can be created that way though. This code works:

```
Option Explicit

' Declaration with implicit creation
Dim c As New Collection

Sub foo()

c.Add "hello", "world"
MsgBox c.Count

End Sub
```

whereas this code doesn't work (you'll get error 429 - ActiveX component can't create object):

```
Option Explicit

' Declaration with implicit creation
Dim w As New Workbook

Sub foo()

MsgBox w.FullName

End Sub
```

Comment: Correct but try to avoid [Auto-Instancing](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx)- means: don't declare and create at the same time via `Dim something As New Object` but instead `Dim something as Object`  and then `Set something = New Object` .

Answer (score 1):

First recommendation I would make is to put `Option Explicit` at the top of your code(above all subs and functions). That will help you know when things are not correct.

```
Dim wkbInventory As Workbook Set wkbInventory = Application.Workbooks("name.xlsm")
```

Will not work.  You will have to do

```
Dim wkbInventory As Workbook
Set wkbInventory = Application.Workbooks("name.xlsm")
```

FYI, there is [late binding versus early binding](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245115) that might help you (see also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580/what-is-the-difference-between-early-and-late-binding) for a an overview) . This is something to learn unrelated to procedures so I'm just providing as an if you already din't know...

You can early bind

```
' Set reference to 'Microsoft Excel 8.0 Object Library' in
' the Project|References dialog (or Tools|References for VB4 or VBA).

' Declare the object as an early-bound object
  Dim oExcel As Excel.Application

  Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

' The Visible property is called via the v-table
  oExcel.Visible = True

' Good practice to explicitly set object variables to "Nothing" when
' done but not mandatory (especially not for local references).
  Set oExcel = Nothing
```

Or late bind

```
' No reference to a type library is needed to use late binding.
' As long as the object supports IDispatch, the method can 
' be dynamically located and invoked at run-time.

' Declare the object as a late-bound object
  Dim oExcel As Object

  Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

' The Visible property is called via IDispatch
  oExcel.Visible = True

' Good practice to explicitly set object variables to "Nothing" when
' done but not mandatory (especially not for local references).
  Set oExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: Your explanation about early binding vs. late binding isn't correct. What you call "late binding" is early binding and what you call "early binding" is auto-instancing. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245115 and http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx  -> "Don't Use Auto-Instancing Object Variables"

Comment: Thanks for the info Axel.  I changed the example.