# Get pgsql variable into VB parameter function

Tags: vba, postgresql, plpgsql

I have this code in VB where I open my connection to the database and connect to my pgsql function..

```vb
Set oCmd = New ADODB.Command    
oCmd.ActiveConnection = GetConnectionString
oCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
oCmd.CommandTimeout = 36000
oCmd.Parameters.Append oCmd.CreateParameter("lngUserId", adInteger, adParamOutput)
oCmd.CommandText = "P_Login"
oCmd.Execute    
g_USRid = oCmd.Parameters("lngUserId")
```

In my pgsql function I have this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION p_login(
OUT lnguserid bigint) RETURNS record AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
BEGIN

--Select USR_Id into lngUserID From tbl_User Where USR_Login = strLogin;
lngUserID := 369;

END;

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
COST 100;
```

The problem is that my variable `g_USRid` doesn't get the value 369. How can I do that?

Comment: That can't be VBScript or you'd be getting `Microsoft VBScript runtime error (1, 1) : Class not defined: 'ADODB'` on the line `Set oCmd = New ADODB.Command`. You sure this isn't VBA which supports [early-binding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10581/692942)? **Edit:** Just realised the tag [has been removed](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42089493/2), will add it back in.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use only one OUT and RETURNS record together.

May be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION p_login(OUT lnguserid bigint)
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION p_login() RETURNS bigint
```

Repaierd version your function (from comment)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION p_login(
       IN strlogin varchar,
       IN strpassword varchar,
      OUT "lngUserId" bigint,
      OUT stroraclelogin varchar,
      OUT stroraclepassword varchar,
      OUT lngprofile bigint,
      OUT interror bigint)
RETURNS record AS $BODY$ Declare 
begin --Select USR_Id into lngUserID From tbl_User Where USR_Login = strLogin;
lngUserID := 369;
end; $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER COST 100; 

SELECT * FROM p_login('1','1');

 lnguserid | stroraclelogin | stroraclepassword | lngprofile | interror 
-----------+----------------+-------------------+------------+----------
       369 |                |                   |            |         
(1 row)
```

Errors:

1) postgr4esql does not have varchar2, just varchar

2) twice `RETURNS record RETURNS record`

To access to result use:

Set rst = cmd.Execute 
MsgBox rst.Fields(1).Value

Comment: i just remove others parameters into the function but the has much more parameters into it but didn't wanted to write them all

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION p_login(
    IN strlogin varchar2,
    IN strpassword varchar2,
    OUT lnguserid bigint,
    OUT stroraclelogin varchar2,
    OUT stroraclepassword varchar2,
    OUT lngprofile bigint,
    OUT interror bigint)
  RETURNS record AS
  RETURNS record AS
$BODY$

Declare

begin

 --Select USR_Id into lngUserID From tbl_User Where USR_Login = strLogin;
lngUserID := 369;

end;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100;

Comment: i want just to ask another question without opening a new discussion...
now i wealing to do so 
_Select USR_Id into lngUserId From tbl_User Where USR_Login = strLogin;_
but it doesn't work.. how can i do that??

Comment: looks like normal sql

Comment: can you run in psql/pgadmin: `Select USR_Id into lngUserId From tbl_User Where USR_Login = 'some login'`  where some login is real user login?

Comment: thanks for your help i found out the problem.. this was due to a commit command i put into my function

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your function. Most importantly, you should not return a `record` but simply the value you are interested in. Furthermore, you can use a much more efficient `sql` language function. Lastly, the function should not be `VOLATILE` (it does not change anything in the database, nor does it depend on changing factors like the current time) but `STRICT` (parameters need to be specified to invoke the function). Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION p_login(strLogin text) RETURNS bigint AS $BODY$
   SELECT USR_Id FROM tbl_User WHERE USR_Login = strLogin;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql STRICT;
```

Note that you have to set the parameter `strLogin` in VB prior to calling the function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
the 'select' statement is in comment..i want just to figure out how to get the 'lngUserId' value into 'g_userID' in my VB code

Answer (score 0):

this is how the function is constructed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION p_login(
    IN strlogin varchar2,
    IN strpassword varchar2,
    OUT lnguserid bigint,
    OUT stroraclelogin varchar2,
    OUT stroraclepassword varchar2,
    OUT lngprofile bigint,
    OUT interror bigint)
  RETURNS record AS
$BODY$

Declare

begin

    --Select USR_Id into lngUserID From tbl_User Where USR_Login = strLogin;
lngUserID := 369;

end;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100;
```

Comment: ok corrected, but still having the same problem... cannot get the 'lngUserId' value into VB

Comment: If you want case sensitivity name of object in PostgreSQL you must use ": "lngUserId", or call it as lnguserid from your progaram: oCmd.Parameters("lnguserid")

Comment: i can't really get what you are saying..please can you give me an example??

Comment: try `oCmd.Parameters("lnguserid")` instead `oCmd.Parameters("lngUserId")` or change argument name in function from `lngUserId` to `"lngUserId"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135181/discussion-between-roman-tkachuk-and-kamfasage).