# Checkpointing keras model: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pickle

It seems like the error has occurred in the past in different contexts [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11157), but I'm not dumping the model directly -- I'm using the ModelCheckpoint callback. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Information:

- Keras version 2.0.8
- Tensorflow version 1.3.0
- Python 3.6

Minimal example to reproduce the error:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = Input(shape=(30,3))
low = tf.constant(np.random.rand(30, 3).astype('float32'))
high = tf.constant(1 + np.random.rand(30, 3).astype('float32'))
clipped_out_position = Lambda(lambda x, low, high: tf.clip_by_value(x, low, high),
                                      arguments={'low': low, 'high': high})(x)

model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=[clipped_out_position])
optimizer = Adam(lr=.1)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="mean_squared_error")
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("debug.hdf", monitor="val_loss", verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode="min")
training_callbacks = [checkpoint]
model.fit(np.random.rand(100, 30, 3), [np.random.rand(100, 30, 3)], callbacks=training_callbacks, epochs=50, batch_size=10, validation_split=0.33)
```

Error output:

```
Train on 67 samples, validate on 33 samples
Epoch 1/50
10/67 [===>..........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1627Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 0.17002, saving model to debug.hdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "debug_multitask_inverter.py", line 19, in <module>
    model.fit(np.random.rand(100, 30, 3), [np.random.rand(100, 30, 3)], callbacks=training_callbacks, epochs=50, batch_size=10, validation_split=0.33)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1631, in fit

▽
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1233, in _fit_loop
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 73, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 414, in on_epoch_end
    self.model.save(filepath, overwrite=True)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2556, in save
    save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 107, in save_model
    'config': model.get_config()
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2397, in get_config
    return copy.deepcopy(config)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 215, in _deepcopy_list
    append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When saving a `Lambda` layer, the `arguments` passed in will also be saved. In this case, it contains two `tf.Tensor`s. It seems that Keras does not support serializing `tf.Tensor` in the model config right now.

However, numpy arrays can be serialized without problem. So instead of passing `tf.Tensor` in `arguments`, you can pass in numpy arrays, and convert them into `tf.Tensor`s in the lambda function.

```py
x = Input(shape=(30,3))
low = np.random.rand(30, 3)
high = 1 + np.random.rand(30, 3)
clipped_out_position = Lambda(lambda x, low, high: tf.clip_by_value(x, tf.constant(low, dtype='float32'), tf.constant(high, dtype='float32')),
                              arguments={'low': low, 'high': high})(x)
```

A problem with the lines above is that, when trying to load this model, you might see a `NameError: name 'tf' is not defined`. That's because TensorFlow is not imported in the file where the `Lambda` layer is reconstructed (core.py).

Changing `tf` into `K.tf` can fix the problem. Also you can replace `tf.constant()` by `K.constant()`, which casts `low` and `high` into float32 tensors automatically.

```py
from keras import backend as K
x = Input(shape=(30,3))
low = np.random.rand(30, 3)
high = 1 + np.random.rand(30, 3)
clipped_out_position = Lambda(lambda x, low, high: K.tf.clip_by_value(x, K.constant(low), K.constant(high)),
                              arguments={'low': low, 'high': high})(x)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the excellent explanation + thorough answer!

Comment: Hi Yu-Yang, I just hit this bug. However I cannot use ndarray instead, cause the tensor I'm passing to lambda is K.shape(), which contains None. Do you have another solution?

Comment: Hi @Moyan, I have no solution right now, but I think you can always rebuild the model with the same code and use `save_weights()`/`load_weights()`. In this case, you'll need to set `save_weights_only=True` in `ModelCheckpoint`.

Comment: I figured it out yesterday. This exception is raised because we trying to serialize a "wandering tf.tensor". See my post below. Thank you for you answer, I won't solve this without your post.

Answer (score 7):

To clarify: this is **not** a problem of Keras being unable to pickle a Tensor (other scenarios possible, see **below**) in a Lambda layer, but rather that the arguments of the python's function (here: a lambda function) are attempted to be serialized independently from the function (here: outside of the context of the lambda function itself). This works for 'static' arguments, but fails otherwise. In order to circumvent it, one should wrap the non-static function arguments in another function.

Here are a couple of workarounds:

---

1. Use **static** variables, such as python/numpy-variables (just a mentioned above):

```
low = np.random.rand(30, 3)
high = 1 + np.random.rand(30, 3)

x = Input(shape=(30,3))
clipped_out_position = Lambda(lambda x: tf.clip_by_value(x, low, high))(x)
```

---

2. Use `functools.partial` to wrap your lambda-function:

```
import functools

clip_by_value = functools.partial(
   tf.clip_by_value,
   clip_value_min=low,
   clip_value_max=high)

x = Input(shape=(30,3))
clipped_out_position = Lambda(lambda x: clip_by_value(x))(x)
```

---

3. Use a **closure** to wrap your lambda-function:

```
low = tf.constant(np.random.rand(30, 3).astype('float32'))
high = tf.constant(1 + np.random.rand(30, 3).astype('float32'))

def clip_by_value(t):
    return tf.clip_by_value(t, low, high)

x = Input(shape=(30,3))
clipped_out_position = Lambda(lambda x: clip_by_value(x))(x)
```

***Notice**: although that you can sometimes drop the creation of explicit `lambda`-function and have this cleaner code snippet instead:*

```
clipped_out_position = Lambda(clip_by_value)(x)
```

*the absence of an extra wrapping layer of a lambda function (that is* `lambda t: clip_by_value(t)`) *might still **lead to the same problem** when doing 'deep-copy' of the function arguments, and **should be avoided**.*

---

4. Finally, you can wrap your model logic into a **separate Keras layer**, which in this particular case may look a bit over-engineered:

```
x = Input(shape=(30,3))
low = Lambda(lambda t: tf.constant(np.random.rand(30, 3).astype('float32')))(x)
high = Lambda(lambda t: tf.constant(1 + np.random.rand(30, 3).astype('float32')))(x)
clipped_out_position = Lambda(lambda x: tf.clip_by_value(*x))((x, low, high))
```

***Notice**: the* `tf.clip_by_value(*x)` *in the last Lambda layer is just an unpacked argument tuple, which can also be written in a more verbose form as* `tf.clip_by_value(x[0], x[1], x[2])` *instead.*

---

(**below**) As a side note: such a scenario, where your lambda-function is trying to capture (a part of) a class instance will also break the serialization (due to a [late binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580/what-is-the-difference-between-early-and-late-binding/10587)):

```
class MyModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.low = np.random.rand(30, 3)
        self.high = 1 + np.random.rand(30, 3)

    def run(self):
        x = Input(shape=(30,3))
        clipped_out_position = Lambda(lambda x: tf.clip_by_value(x, self.low, self.high))(x)
        model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=[clipped_out_position])
        optimizer = Adam(lr=.1)
        model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="mean_squared_error")
        checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("debug.hdf", monitor="val_loss", verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode="min")
        training_callbacks = [checkpoint]
        model.fit(np.random.rand(100, 30, 3), 
                 [np.random.rand(100, 30, 3)], callbacks=training_callbacks, epochs=50, batch_size=10, validation_split=0.33)

MyModel().run()
```

Which can be solved by assuring an early binding by this *default argument* trick:

```
        (...)
        clipped_out_position = Lambda(lambda x, l=self.low, h=self.high: tf.clip_by_value(x, l, h))(x)
        (...)
```

Comment: I'm using the method 3 (a closure to wrap lambda function). It trains alright, but whenever I try to load the saved model I obtain a `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` on the line where the lambda function is called. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Gianluca Micchi Sep 25 '19 at 12:42
I encountered the same problem. When I used a closure to avoid the lambda model save problem, I can not load the model. I obtain a TypeError: 'str' object is not callable'

Answer (score 3):

See my post at https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8343#issuecomment-470376703.

This exception is raised because you're trying to serialize a tf.tensor, so any methods that will avoid this serialization would work. including:

- Not serialize it: save model weights only, because this serialization happens when you're trying to save the model structure with json/yaml string.
- Eliminate tensorflow tensors: make sure every tensor in your model is produced by a keras layer. Or use ndarray data instead if possible, just like what @Yu-Yang suggested.