# TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects When trying to save keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I receive the error: `TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects` when trying to save my keras model. I believe it has to do with the lambda layers I'm using, but I'm not sure which ones to fix.

So far (seen in code), I've tried following answer 3 of this question: [Checkpointing keras model: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47066635/checkpointing-keras-model-typeerror-cant-pickle-thread-lock-objects)

I did this by extracting the arguments out of the lambdas so they don't cause problems. This did not seem to fix the error, though. I'm running on Windows 10, python 3.7 using anaconda.

Here is the model I'm trying to save:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Lambda, Add, Multiply, Conv2D, Input
import keras.backend as K
import functools
import keras
from keras.models import Model

def resBlock_Keras(x, channels=64, kernel_size=[3,3], scale=1):
    tmp = Conv2D(channels, kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    tmp = Conv2D(channels, kernel_size, padding='same')(tmp)
    multiply_by_scale = functools.partial(
        tf.multiply,
        scale
    )
    add_input = functools.partial(
        tf.add,
        x
    )
    tmp = Lambda(lambda q: multiply_by_scale(q))(tmp)
    return Lambda(lambda q: add_input(q))(tmp)

def PS_Keras(X, r, color=False):
    if color:
        split = functools.partial(
            tf.split,
            num_or_size_splits=3,
            axis=3
        )
        concat = functools.partial(
            tf.concat,
            axis=3
        )
        Xc = Lambda(lambda x: split(x))(X)
        shifts = [_phase_shift_keras(x, r) for x in Xc]
        X = Lambda(lambda q: concat(q))(shifts)
    else:
        X = _phase_shift_keras(X, r)
    return X

def _phase_shift_keras(I, r):
    bsize, a, b, c = I.get_shape().as_list()
    bsize = K.shape(I)[0] # Handling Dimension(None) type for undefined batch dim
    X = K.reshape(I, [bsize, a, b, c//(r*r),r, r]) # bsize, a, b, c/(r*r), r, r
    X = K.permute_dimensions(X, (0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3))  # bsize, a, b, r, r, c/(r*r)
    #Keras backend does not support tf.split, so in future versions this could be nicer
    X = [X[:,i,:,:,:,:] for i in range(a)] # a, [bsize, b, r, r, c/(r*r)
    X = K.concatenate(X, 2)  # bsize, b, a*r, r, c/(r*r)
    X = [X[:,i,:,:,:] for i in range(b)] # b, [bsize, r, r, c/(r*r)
    X = K.concatenate(X, 2)  # bsize, a*r, b*r, c/(r*r)
    return X

def upsample_keras(x,scale=2,features=64,activation='relu'):
    assert scale in [2,3,4]
    x = Conv2D(features,[3,3],activation=activation,padding='same')(x)
    if scale == 2:
        ps_features = 3*(scale**2)
        x = Conv2D(ps_features,[3,3],activation=activation,padding='same')(x)
        ps = functools.partial(
            PS_Keras,
            r=2,
            color=True
        )
        x = Lambda(lambda q: ps(q))(x)
    elif scale == 3:
        ps_features =3*(scale**2)
        x = Conv2D(ps_features,[3,3],activation=activation,padding='same')(x)
        ps = functools.partial(
            PS_Keras,
            r=3,
            color=True
        )
        x = Lambda(lambda q: ps(q))(x)
    elif scale == 4:
        ps_features = 3*(2**2)
        ps = functools.partial(
            PS_Keras,
            r=2,
            color=True
        )
        for i in range(2):
            x = Conv2D(ps_features,[3,3],activation=activation,padding='same')(x)
            x = Lambda(lambda q: ps(q))(x)
    return x

def subtract_mean(x):
    return tf.subtract(x,127.0)

def build_model(img_size=32,num_layers=32,feature_size=64,scale=2,output_channels=3):
    MEAN_PIXEL = 127.0
    MIN_PIXEL = 0.0
    MAX_PIXEL = 255.0

    scaling_factor = 0.1
    img_size = img_size
    scale=scale
    input = Input(shape=(img_size,img_size,output_channels))
    curr_layer = Lambda(lambda x: subtract_mean(x))(input)
    first_conv = Conv2D(feature_size, [3,3], padding='same')(curr_layer)
    curr_layer = first_conv
    for i in range(num_layers):
        curr_layer = resBlock_Keras(curr_layer, feature_size, scale=scaling_factor)
    curr_layer = Conv2D(feature_size, [3,3],padding='same')(curr_layer)
    curr_layer = Add()([curr_layer, first_conv])

    clip_by_value = functools.partial(
    tf.clip_by_value,
    clip_value_min=MIN_PIXEL,
    clip_value_max=MAX_PIXEL)

    upsample = functools.partial(
        upsample_keras,
        scale = scale,
        features = feature_size,
        activation=None
    )

    curr_layer = Lambda(lambda x: upsample(x))(curr_layer)
    output = Lambda(lambda x: clip_by_value(x))(curr_layer)

    model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
    model.compile(loss='mae',optimizer='adam')
    model.summary()
    model.save("model.h5")

build_model()
```

Here's the full stack trace I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 125, in <module>
    build_model()
  File "tmp.py", line 123, in build_model
    model.save("model.h5")
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1090, in save
    save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 382, in save_model
    _serialize_model(model, f, include_optimizer)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 83, in _serialize_model
    model_config['config'] = model.get_config()
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 931, in get_config
    return copy.deepcopy(config)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 215, in _deepcopy_list
    append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 220, in _deepcopy_tuple
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 220, in _deepcopy_tuple
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 220, in _deepcopy_tuple
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 220, in _deepcopy_tuple
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Users\pwatm\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```