# tensorflow version 1 Cant save model for website use

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model, load_model
from keras.optimizers import SGD
# from keras.optimizers import gradient_descent_v2 
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from keras import backend as K


config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
K.set_session(sess)

def convnet_model_():
    vgg_model = VGG16(weights=None, include_top=False)
    x = vgg_model.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.6)(x)
    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.6)(x)
    x = Lambda(lambda x_: K.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))(x)
    convnet_model = Model(inputs=vgg_model.input, outputs=x)
    return convnet_model


def deep_rank_model():
    convnet_model = convnet_model_()
    first_input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
    first_conv = Conv2D(96, kernel_size=(8, 8), strides=(16, 16), padding='same')(first_input)
    first_max = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(4, 4), padding='same')(first_conv)
    first_max = Flatten()(first_max)
    first_max = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))(first_max)

    second_input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
    second_conv = Conv2D(96, kernel_size=(8, 8), strides=(32, 32), padding='same')(second_input)
    second_max = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(7, 7), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(second_conv)
    second_max = Flatten()(second_max)
    second_max = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))(second_max)

    merge_one = concatenate([first_max, second_max])

    merge_two = concatenate([merge_one, convnet_model.output])
    emb = Dense(4096)(merge_two)
    l2_norm_final = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))(emb)

    final_model = Model(inputs=[first_input, second_input, convnet_model.input], outputs=l2_norm_final)

    return final_model
```

I am refering to online code to perform a deep ranking model training...I would like to save the model but fail to. I know that the lambda layer is stopping me to save the model.
As I got from [Checkpointing keras model: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47066635/checkpointing-keras-model-typeerror-cant-pickle-thread-lock-objects,I) knew that the tensorflow object may stop me form saving the model

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-bdb0097d23ba> in <module>()
      3 deep_rankmodel.save_weights(model_path)
      4 f = open('deepranking.json','w')
----> 5 f.write(deep_rankmodel.to_json())
      6 f.close()

29 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    167                     reductor = getattr(x, "__reduce_ex__", None)
    168                     if reductor:
--> 169                         rv = reductor(4)
    170                     else:
    171                         reductor = getattr(x, "__reduce__", None)

TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

Here are some snippet of the debug screen

[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTyJU.png)
Btw
Is there any way of not using saved json model to load the model in server? Can I reconstruct the model in server using javascript or anything?