# VBA Button pressing on IE explanation

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I have managed to get my code to work, but only by searching the internet and finding something that worked, I don't actually understand why.

Could someone please explain why when I used

```
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
```

trying to press a button gave me the error

> Object invoked has disconnected from clients

but using

```
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
```

has worked?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do early binding of IE in VBA. Thus, you need to do it like this:

`Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer` or `Dim IE As New InternetExplorer`, after adding the "Microsoft Internet Controls" library to the project (c:\windows\syswow64\ieframe.dll).

In general, if you want to do late binding, you should do it like this:

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

[What is the difference between Early and Late Binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580/what-is-the-difference-between-early-and-late-binding) and [my understanding about late and early binding](https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-early-and-late-binding/)

Comment: `Dim ie As New InternetExplorer`
    `ie.Visible = True` does work

Comment: @jsotola with which library?

Comment: win7 ... `Microsoft Internet Controls` ... c:\windows\syswow64\ieframe.dll