# Why is defining a variable with excel.application generating a user defined variable error?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Am reading an Access 365 data base, creating an error report, processing the data and outputting an excel spreadsheet.  Having dickens of a time declaring the variables. excel.application is throwing a user defined variable error.

Also, like to have a recommendation on referencing the cells in the spreadsheet.  I plan to provide column names in line one but not sure this will suffice.  Do i need to reference cells explicitly?

I have done a lot of researching and reading but have not been able to ascertain a solution to this excel.application user defined error problem.  Have tried lots of variations but unable to ascertain a solution.

Can probably tell this is my first time trying to create an excel output file.   Please help!!

Many THANKS!!!

```
'  Error Report File
RptLoc = "C:\Users\XXXX\OneDrive\TGS Committee Cloud\TGS Columbia Abstract Index Project\DataBase Load to OurRoots & AWS\Load Test File - 50 Recs - Fix Dates - Errors.txt"       ' Create error file.
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set myFile = fso.CreateTextFile(RptLoc, True)       'Create Error text file
TXTLine = "Fixing date field has started."
myFile.WriteLine (TXTLine)

'  Open INPUT File
strSQL = "SELECT [Indexing].* FROM [Indexing]"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set RS = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)   'open input file - Columbia Abstract Database

' Create and open excel output file.
Dim xls As Excel.Application   
Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet

FileLoc = "C:\Users\XXXX\OneDrive\TGS Committee Cloud\TGS Volunteer WorkSpace\Col Abstr\Testing\New Excel test file.xlsx"

Set xls = New Excel.Application     '**THIS LINE IS GENERATING USER DEFINED 
                                            ERROR.  What am i doing wrong?** 
Set wkb = xls.Workbooks.Open(FileLoc)
Set wks = wkb.Worksheets(1)

wks.Name = "New Index"    'Giving spreadsheet a name.

'wkb.Close True

'Set wks = Nothing
'Set wkb = Nothing
'xls.Quit
'Set xls = Nothing

Print .debug; "Worked!!"`

And the code goes on....
```

Comment: VBE Tools > References, Check `Microsoft Excel x.0 Object Library`

Comment: Or use late binding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580/what-is-the-difference-between-early-and-late-binding

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer was this contribution by taller on Jan 3, 2024,
"VBE Tools > References, Check Microsoft Excel x.0 Object Library – taller Jan 3 at 3:24".

I added this reference and all the problems disappeared. Many thanks to taller!!